# Calling an impl method from another impl method

Tags: rust

It seems I can't call the method of the same struct in Rust or maybe I don't understand something:

```
struct St1 {
  aa: String
}

impl St1 {
  pub fn method1() -> String {
    //....
    method2() //error: unresolved name method2
  }

  pub fn method2() -> String {
    //....
  }
}
```

Is this how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the method you are calling.

```
struct St1 {
    aa: String
}

impl St1 {
    pub fn method1() -> String {
        St1::method2()
    }

    pub fn method2() -> String {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

On the off chance that you mean for these methods to be instance methods, then you still have to fully qualify them, but using `self` instead:

```
struct St1 {
    aa: String
}

impl St1 {
    pub fn method1(&self) -> String {
        self.method2()
    }

    pub fn method2(&self) -> String {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Note that Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: 1) how can I access `aa`?
2) is it a recommended style to use Impl or is it better to use "pure" functions without wrapping them into Impl?

Comment: @jawanam (1) is another question and should be asked separately. It's also covered by [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), which you should **definitely** read. (2) is "it depends". Is your function highly related to the struct? If so, I'd use `impl`.